# Who did Taskmaster's stunts?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, production, black-widow-2021

There's a pretext for this question which is a spoiler:

> It is only revealed very late in the movie that the Taskmaster is actually Antonia Dreykov, a woman.

So

> in order for this reveal to work, the filmmakers chose to obscure her gender in order to take advantage of our natural assumption that the Taskmaster is a man (both due to biases and the character's history in the comics).  The armor/outfit is designed in a very gender-neutral way that obscures her form and avoids any obvious cue that Taskmaster is a woman, and likely is in fact designed it a way to make the character appear male (at least to any extent that superhero costumes lacking any obvious cues are perceived as male).

> Conveniently, the Taskmaster always wears the outfit/armor and doesn't speak, so this goal is more easily achieved.

> In addition, the Taskmaster adopts a wide variety of fighting styles, so again, any stereotypically masculine or feminine fighting styles are irrelevant.

> So, the bottom line is, given the need for the character to appear male until the reveal, was the character stunted by predominantly male stunt actors?

**Which stunt actor(s) played Taskmaster?   Was it different actors for different fighting styles?**

Answer (score 10):

The lead stunt double for Taskmaster was [Andy Lister](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Andy_Lister). This is noted on the IMDb pages for [*Black Widow*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3480822/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm) and the [stunt performer](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4821843/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr1518). Andy Lister talks about this [on Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/CRLJ0BDgH2g/):

> I’m honoured and proud to have been the stunt double and in suit performer for Taskmaster in Black Widow!
> It was one of my most favourite movies to work on!!
> Such an awesome team!
> Shout outs to @allstunts @flostunts @cateshortland the fight team @jyou10 @daren_nop @cali_nelle @dawe_szatarski @troystunt my fighting partners #scarlettjohansson @cc_ice_stunts @micheala_ashley @kella.mcallister @dkharbour @johnmacfilms my fellow TMs @daren_nop @enci_fulop @amy_sturdivant Daryl Andrews rigging team Dermot, Dan Thomas, @daveboyl @tonychristianstunts @ronankearns86 Byron, Blackie, Nathan costume dept keeping me together @janytemime_costume_designer @dan.grace.1174 Nick, Terry and Paul you legends!

Note that the Taskmaster, Antonia Dreykov, actress is a stunt actress herself. Olga Kurulenko goes into some details on her training in the past for previous films in the below interview. Presumably she did some of the stunts herself.

> “I do learn quicker. Certain moves I kind of know, as well as their starting point and stance,” Kurylenko tells The Hollywood Reporter. “It makes it easier for the stunt team to explain it to me, and based on their comments, they’ll notice that I’ve done it before.”
>
> <sub>[The Hollywood Reporter, How Olga Kurylenko Won ‘Bond’ and Narrowly Lost ‘Wonder Woman’](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-features/anything-could-have-happened-how-olga-kurylenko-lost-wonder-woman-1260651/)</sub>